# Next Js Server Side Api Read and Write JSON

Tags: javascript, json, api, next.js, fs

I'm trying to write a basic local api for myself using Next.js, it is a timeline generator, and I am stuck at actually reading the file from the api folder.

What do I want in my local aplication:

1.A simple page where I can input an event, with a date and description

2.Open a list.json file somewhere and push that new event to that json file, writing on it.

What I am currently doing and where I am stuck:

I am aware we cant write on files on the client side, so I started looking at the api routes in next js to access the JSON file, but I cannot even manage to read it!

I have an api folder inside pages folder, and in this api folder I have two files: one is the list.json file, where I previously manually write some events with respective dates; and the other is getlist.js, with this code:

```
var fs = require('fs');

export default function getList(req, res) {
    const rawList = fs.readFile('list.json');
    var list = JSON.parse(rawList);
    res.json(list);
}
```

Now on the pages folder I have a index.js file where I try to access this getlist.js api using getStaticProps(), like this:

```
import getlist from './api/getlist'

export async function getStaticProps(){

    var list = getlist();

    return {
        props: {
            list
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using other stuff, like the fecth function, to get to getlist.js, but nothing I do seems to work.

Can anyone help me?

And since I'm already in here, how would I manage to get the input from the form I already have in my client side page and write it to that list.json file in my api folder?

Comment: You probably mean to use `readFileSync` as `readFile` requires a callback function.

Comment: You should call `fs.readFile('list.json')` directly from `getStaticProps`. `getStaticProps` only runs on the server, you should call any server-specific code directly from it.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! But now how can I handle a form submit to write on that file? I can't use getStaticProps to run server side code once the built is done everytime I press the form submit, so what other mechanism I should use?

Comment: I coudn't figure out how to do this in Next witthout having to use a custom express server, so now Im not using next at all.

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways how you can read json in next.js:

- Import inside `getStaticProps` [https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation]

```
    export async function getStaticProps(context){
      const example = await import('./api/example.json');
      return {props: {example: example.default}}
    }
```

- Import or read in `handler` function inside `api` folder [https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction]:

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    
    export default async function handler (req, res) {
      const example = await fs.readFile('./example.json');
      return res.status(200).json({example});
    }
```

In order to write *.json file you need to send request with value to the server api (`handler` from `api` folder that was mentioned before).

That's how the part to write json will look like:

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    
    export default async function handler(req, res) {
      //...
      if (req.method === 'POST'){
        fs.writeFileSync('./example.json', JSON.stringify(req.body))
        return res.status(200).json({});
      }
      //...
    }
```